# SSL issue for Media Library Item URL in Sitecore Rich Text Editor

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

We are using Sitecore 6.2 and required to use SSL on the Sitecore admin site.

Everything works perfectly except that when saving the content in the Rich Text editor (clicking ACCEPT button), all URLs to the media library items will be added with "https://....(our domain address)". For example,

"~/media/70E900F781E24A66915FA97E283C148E"

to

"https://www.mywebsite.com/~/media/70E900F781E24A66915FA97E283C148E"

The workaround is to go to HTML editor and manually remove the "https://..." part. If we remove the SSL, then the addition won't happen and it'll work fine.

I'm assuming having the Sitecore admin site on SSL is not rare so I wonder if there is a way to deal with this. Thanks!

Comment: Interesting issue. I have searched through some Sitecore DLL code, but couldn't find the answer. Maybe you can contact support about this?

Answer (score 1):

You could probably de-compile and tweak the out-of-the-box LinkProvider class and change the `ExpandDynamicLinks()` method to replace `https://` with `http://`

The class is defined in the `web.config` in this setting:

```
<linkManager defaultProvider="sitecore">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="sitecore" type="Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider, Sitecore.Kernel" addAspxExtension="true" alwaysIncludeServerUrl="false" encodeNames="true" languageEmbedding="never" languageLocation="filePath" shortenUrls="true" useDisplayName="false" />
  </providers>
</linkManager>
```

You could re-create it as a custom provider and set the `defaultProvider` to your custom class:

```
<linkManager defaultProvider="custom">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="sitecore" type="Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider, Sitecore.Kernel" addAspxExtension="true" alwaysIncludeServerUrl="false" encodeNames="true" languageEmbedding="never" languageLocation="filePath" shortenUrls="true" useDisplayName="false" />
    <add name="custom" type="CustomUtility.LinkProvider, CustomUtility" addAspxExtension="true" alwaysIncludeServerUrl="false" encodeNames="true" languageEmbedding="never" languageLocation="filePath" shortenUrls="true" useDisplayName="false" />
  </providers>
</linkManager>
```

If you don't have a de-compiler, [ILSpy is a free one](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx).

Comment: Sounds scary. Why you need to decompile? Inherit and override should be enough.

Comment: Right, but you need to de-compile it to see how you need to change the method. In your `override` version you will likely have a lot of the original code but with some tweaks. If you don't de-compile as a reference, how do you know what you're even going to write?

Comment: I use Reflector- it allows to see code with minimum actions from my side